# apache not releasing connection

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

i dont know why apache is not releasing connection.Its keeping connection for a long time.
Here is the status from server-status.

> Server Version: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.7 with
>   Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o Server Built: Feb 14 2012
>   19:59:02
>
> Parent Server Generation: 1 Server uptime: 2 days 8 hours 3 minutes 45
>   seconds Total accesses: 71124 - Total Traffic: 365.0 MB CPU Usage:
>   u73.44 s9.32 cu.67 cs0 - .0413% CPU load .352 requests/sec - 1896
>   B/second - 5.3 kB/request **555** requests currently being processed, 35
>   idle workers
>   WWWWWW_WWWWWWWWWWWWWW.WWWWW.WWWWW.WWWWWWWWWW.W.WW.WWWWWW_W.WWWWW
>   WWWWW.WW.WWWWWWW_WWWWWWWWWWWWWW.WWWWWWWWW.WW.WWWWWWWWWWWWW.W_CWW
>   WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.WWW_WW_WWWWWWW_WWW.WWWWWWWW_
>   WWWWWWWWWWWWWW.WW_WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW_WWWWW.WWWWW_WWW_W_WWWWWWWWW
>   WWWWWWWWW_WWWW.WWWWWWWWWWWWW.WWWWWWWW_WW_WWW_W_WW_WWWWWWWWWW.._W
>   WWWWWW_WW_WWWWWWWWWWWWW_WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW_WWWWWWWWWWWWW_WWWWWWW
>   WWWWWW_WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW_WWW_WWWWWWW_WW_WWW.WWWWWWWW.WWWWW..W
>   WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.WWW_WWWWWWW_WWWWWWWWWWW.WWWWWWWW.WWWWWWWW
>   WWWWWWWW.WWW.WWWWWWW.WW.WWWWWWW.WWWWWWWW.W.WWW.WWWWWW.WWW.WW.WWW
>   WWWWWWWWWWW.WWWWWWW.WWW.WWWWWWWWW.W.WWWWWWWWWWWW.W.WW......*W.*.
>   ........W..............*......................W.W...............
>   ................................................................
>   ................................ Scoreboard Key: "*" Waiting for
>   Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request, "W" Sending Reply,
>   "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup, "C" Closing connection, "L"
>   Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing, "I" Idle cleanup of worker, "."
>   Open slot with no current process

here is the extended status.. http://pastebin.com/5KtWZRLe

Where can be the problem?
**max client** is set to 800

**spare-server** 35 
using ubuntu 11.04 and mysql 5

using CSF firewall and it is set not to limit request to port 80

Comment: Could you clarify what symptoms you are seeing that lead you believe there is a problem? You have 35 idle workers ... so looks like you have room to take more requests.

Comment: but still apache is holding nearly 400 children for each slow connections,and not allowing new IP's to connect through....What can be the reason..This occur only for slow 2G connections.

Comment: Do you have keepalive enabled? Post the relevant portions of your httpd conf(s), please.

Comment: KeepAliveTimeout 10
We tried turning of the KepAlive still, it didnt help.